# Can someone point me in the MUI documentation where the proper syntax can be found for these few commented code lines?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The ThemeProvider with theme={theme} has already been provided. That aside, I will post two separate files of code. In these files are the commented sections where the code isn't working when I try to implement my FlexContentBoxHeader for my login box.

```js
import { createTheme, colors } from "@mui/material";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: colors.blueGrey["A700"],
      light: colors.blueGrey[100],
      dark: colors.blueGrey[900],
      contrastText: colors.amber[50],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: colors.amber[800],
      light: colors.amber[300],
      dark: colors.amber[700],
      contrastText: colors.amber[50],
    },
    myTextColor: {
      main: colors.amber[50],
    },
  },

  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: "contained",
        color: "secondary",
        size: "small",
      },
    },
    MuiTabs: {
      defaultProps: {
        TabIndicatorProps: { background: "myTextColor.main" },
        indicatorColor: "secondary",
        textColor: "inherit",
      },
    },
    MuiTypography: {
      styleOverrides: {
        ".&MuiTypography-root": {
          color: "secondary.textContrast", //How do I write the syntax to override the default text color?
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

---

```js
import { styled, Typography } from "@mui/material";

const FlexContentBoxHeader = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  variant: "h2", //This isn't working.
  padding: "24px",
  textAlign: "center",
}));

export default FlexContentBoxHeader;
```

---

Where should I look in the MUI doc for the //commented code lines above?

Comment: Variant is not a CSS property so maybe you can't use this way. You have to pass variant as a props when FlexContentBoxHeader will be used.

Comment: So in other words, it is impossible to change the default variant in styled? What about setting a custom theme color for typography?

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: colors.blueGrey["A700"],
      light: colors.blueGrey[100],
      dark: colors.blueGrey[900],
      contrastText: colors.amber[50],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: colors.amber[800],
      light: colors.amber[300],
      dark: colors.amber[700],
      contrastText: colors.amber[50],
    },
    myTextColor: {
      main: colors.amber[50],
    },
  },

  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: "contained",
        color: "secondary",
        size: "small",
      },
    },
    MuiTabs: {
      defaultProps: {
        TabIndicatorProps: { background: "myTextColor.main" },
        indicatorColor: "secondary",
        textColor: "inherit",
      },
    },

   //Overrides Typography component's color and fontSize
    MuiTypography: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontSize: '5rem',
          color: '#0091ea'
        },
        h1: {
          fontSize: '5rem',
          color: '#795548'
        },
        h2: {
          fontSize: '5rem',
          color: colors.amber[800]
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

**You can experiment and customize more and more.**
Here is some link from the MUI documentation related to these codes
1.[Typography Global class and Description](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/typography/)
2.[Components Customization](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides) 3.[How to customize](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/) 4.[MUI styled API](https://mui.com/system/styled/)

[This youtube video from the current time to end helped me a lot you can flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyqpbNgrW3o&t=3343s)